# haveing some problem with cog cant run it(discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

soo My cog is not working no commands or anything

the code (main.py)

```
import os, discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import re
from discord import Colour as C
import json
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
import logging
intents= discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
async def load_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            # cut off the .py from the file name
            await Bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
token = ('nope')
swears = ["(.+)?[kK](\\s*|\\.*)?[1iI](\\s*|\\.*)?[rR][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[kK](\\s*|\\.*)?[oO0](\\s*|\\.*)?[sS3$][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[kK](\\s*|\\.*)?[oO0](\\s*|\\.*)?[bB](\\s|\\.)?[sS3$][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[kK](\\s*|\\.*)?[oO0](\\s*|\\.*)?[oO0](\\s?)[nN][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[kK](\\s*|\\.*)?[uU](\\s*|\\.*)?[nN][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[kK](\\s*|\\.*)?[yYuU](\\s*|\\.*)?[ss$][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[nN](\\s*|\\.*)?[iI1](\\s*|\\.*)?[gG][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[jJgG](\\s*|\\.*)?[eE3](\\s*|\\.*)?[nN](\\s*|\\.*)?[dD](\\s*|\\.*)?[eE3][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[fF](\\s*|\\.*)?[uU](\\s*|\\.*)?[cC](\\s*|\\.*)?[kK][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[dD](\\s*|\\.*)?[iI1](\\s*|\\.*)?[cC](\\s*|\\.*)?[kK][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[pP](\\s*|\\.*)?[uUoO](\\s*|\\.*)?[sS$3](\\s*|\\.*)?([sS$3](\\s*|\\.*))?[yYiI1][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[pP](\\s*|\\.*)?[eE3](\\s*|\\.*)?[nN](\\s*|\\.*)?[iI1](\\s*|\\.*)?[sS3][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[cC](\\s*|\\.*)?[uU](\\s*|\\.*)?[mM][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[eE](\\s*|\\.*)?[jJ](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[cC](\\s*|\\.*)?[uU](\\s*|\\.*)?[lL](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[tT](\\s*|\\.*)?[iI1](\\s*|\\.*)?[oO0](\\s*|\\.*)?[nN][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[mM](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[sS](\\s*|\\.*)?[tT](\\s*|\\.*)?[uU](\\s*|\\.*)?[rR](\\s*|\\.*)?[bB](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[tT](\\s*|\\.*)?[iI1](\\s*|\\.*)?[oO0](\\s*|\\.*)?[nN][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[sS](\\s*|\\.*)?[eE3](\\s*|\\.*)?[xX][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[Ss](\\s*|\\.*)?[hH](\\s*|\\.*)?[iI1](\\s*|\\.*)?[tT][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[Ss](\\s*|\\.*)?[lL](\\s*|\\.*)?[uU](\\s*|\\.*)?[tT][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[sS](\\s*|\\.*)?[sS][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[nN](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[lL][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[rR](\\s*|\\.*)?[ee3](\\s*|\\.*)?[tT](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[rR](\\s*|\\.*)?[dD][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[vV](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[gG](\\s*|\\.*)?[iI1](\\s*|\\.*)?[nN](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[oO0](\\s*|\\.*)?[rR](\\s*|\\.*)?[gG](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[sS](\\s*|\\.*)?[mM][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[jJ](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[qQ][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[jJ](\\s*|\\.*)?[aA](\\s*|\\.*)?[gG](\\s*|\\.*)?[hH][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[gG](\\s*|\\.*)?[oO0](\\s*|\\.*)?[hH][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[wH](\\s*|\\.*)?[hH](\\s*|\\.*)?[oO0](\\s*|\\.*)?[rR](\\s*|\\.*)?[eE3][^o]*(\\s?).*",
"(.+)?[pP](\\s*|\\.*)?[oO0](\\s*|\\.*)?[rR](\\s*|\\.*)?[nN][^o]*(\\s?).*"]


Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents=intents, help_command=None)
activity_string = 'on {} servers.'.format(len(Bot.guilds))





 
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():

    print('Potato Cat is ready :D')

    servers = len(Bot.guilds)
    members = 0
    for guild in Bot.guilds:
        members += guild.member_count - 1

    await Bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(
        type = discord.ActivityType.watching,
        name = f'{servers} servers and {members} members'
    ))
    print(f'{Bot.user} is connected')
@Bot.command()
async def Users(ctx):
    with open('users.txt','w') as f:
        async for member in ctx.guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
            print("{},{}".format(member,member.id), file=f)

    print("done")

  #The anti Swear
#@Bot.event
#async def on_message(message):
     #await Bot.process_commands(message)
     #messageContent = message.content
     #messagee = messageContent.lower()
     #for word in swears:
        #if re.findall(word,messagee):
            #await messageContent.delete()
            #msg=await message.channel.send("Dont use that word!") 
            #await asyncio.sleep(3)
            #await msg.delete()
    #The anti Swear



@Bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = Bot.get_channel(839451902039293962)
    await channel.send(f'Hey welcome to my server {member.mention}, hope you enjoy this server!')
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
    await member.add_roles(role)


@Bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = Bot.get_channel(839451902039293962)
    await channel.send(f'Why You left Man :[ {member.mention}')

  

@Bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, member:discord.Member,*, message):
    if isinstance(ctx.channel,discord.DMChannel):
        await member.send(f'{ctx.member.mention} has a message for you: \n {message}')

@Bot.command(name='clear', help='this command will clear msgs')
async def clear(ctx, amount = 50): # Change amount
  if ctx.message.author.id == (706092920205344818):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Just did my job and clean this place!", colour=C.blue())
    embed.add_field(name=f'cleared {amount} message',value=f"I love this clean chat")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  else:
    embed.add_field(name=f"{ctx.author.mention} you are not allowed daddy!",value=f"you need to try harder THEN That")
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} you are not allowed daddy!")
    


with open('reports.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  try:
    report = json.load(f)
  except ValueError:
    report = {}
    report['users'] = []



intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "", intents = intents)



@Bot.command(pass_context = True)
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True)
async def warn(ctx,user:discord.User,*reason:str):
  author = ctx.author
  if not reason:
    await ctx.send("Please provide a reason")
    return
  reason = ' '.join(reason)
  await ctx.send(f'**{user.mention} has been warned by {author.name}.**')
  await user.send(f'You have been warned in **{ctx.guild.name}** by **{author.name}**.')
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if current_user['name'] == user.name:
      current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
      break
  else:
    report['users'].append({
      'name':user.name,
      'reasons': [reason,]
    })
  with open('reports.json','w+') as f:
    json.dump(report,f)

  with open('reports.json','w+') as f:
    json.dump(report,f)
  if len(report['users']) >= 7:
    await user.kick(reason='You reached 7 warnings')


@Bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def warnings(ctx,user:discord.User):
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if user.name == current_user['name']:
      embed = discord.Embed(title="WARNING'S LIST", colour=C.purple())
      embed.add_field(name=f"**{user.name} has been reported {len(current_user['reasons'])} times : {','.join(current_user['reasons'])}**", value="kharab kari kardi warn dadan bet")
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      break
  else:
    embed = discord.Embed(title="WARNING's LIST", colour=C.purple())
    embed.add_field(name=f"**{user.name} has never been reported**", value="barikala warn nadadan bet xD")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
discord.utils.setup_logging()
async def main():
        Bot.load_extension("kickCog")
        await Bot.start(token)
asyncio.run(main())
#    embed = discord.Embed(title="you have given someone a ROLE", colour=C.red())
#    embed.add_field(name=f'User {member.mention} has been banned for {reason}',value=f"have fun getting BANNED :] {member.mention} ")
```

I would be happy to know what is wrong?
the cog:

```
import os, discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import re
from discord import Colour as C
import json
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions



class kicki:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


@commands.command(pass_context=True)    
async def kick(self ,ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if reason==None:
      reason=" no reason provided"
    await ctx.guild.kick(member)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="SOMEONE GOT KICKED!", colour=C.orange())
    embed.add_field(name=f'User {member.mention} has been kicked for {reason}',value=f"HAVE FUN GETTING KICKED DUMMY {member.mention}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(kicki(bot))
```

i wanted to put it in a FOLDER but it didnt work but please if someone is going to fix it please put it inside a folder named commands
i would be soo happy if someone could help me becuz my brain is not working anymore i searched every PROBLEM that was near mine but nope didnt work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of problems here:

- Your cog class is not subclassing `commands.Cog`
- You're not awaiting `load_extension`
- Your `setup` is not async
- You're not awaiting `add_cog`
- Your `kick` command is not indented inside if your cog
- Don't change presence in `on_ready` (preferably, don't do anything at all)

If you want to load a cog from a separate folder, the path to that cog must have folders separated by dots (`.`).

For example, if your file structure looks like this:

```
main.py

/commands
  -  kickCog.py
```

then you have to load it as `commands.kickCog`

Comment: one thing how i can INDENT it in my cog
yea i fixed some of those problem after i posted this

Comment: You may want to learn a bit more Python before making a Discord bot. A class' methods have to be indented inside of it. Indentation is the whitespace at the beginning of a line. Python doesn't use `curly brackets { }` like some other languages, but it goes off of indentation instead. Your `kick` command has 0 whitespace next to it, so it's at the top level instead of inside the class. Also, if you modify your code & get new issues after posting, you should update your question to reflect that.